# Clarification about equality regarding integrals

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I'm reading Brezis ch. 8 and got stuck in a passage of lemma 8.2 pag. 205.

Let $I=(a,b)$, let $g \in L_{loc}^1(I)$, for a fixed $y_0 \in I$, set $$ v(x) = \int_{y_0}^x g(t)dt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x \in I$$
Then $v \in C(I)$ and $$ \int_I v \varphi' = - \int_I g \varphi \ \ \ \forall \varphi \in C_c^1(I) $$

> **PROOF**
>   \begin{align}
> \int_I v \varphi' &= \int_I \left[ \int_{y_0}^x g(t) dt \right] \varphi'(x)dx \ \ \ \ (1) \\ &= -\int_{a}^{y_0}dx \int_x^{y_0} g(t)\varphi'(x)dt + \int_{y_0}^b dx \int_{y_0}^x g(t)\varphi'(x)dt \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
> \end{align}
>   By Fubini's Theorem, \begin{align} \int_I v \varphi' &= - \int_a^{y_0} g(t) dt \int_a^t \varphi'(x) dx + \int_{y_0}^b g(t) dt \int_t^b \varphi'(x)dx  \ \ \ \ (3) \\ &= - \int_I g(t)\varphi(t)dt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4)
> \end{align}

I've already worked out all the details except the proof of the equivalence of line (2) and line (3). In other words, I can't understand how from line (2) we can go to line (3) using Fubini.

Every hints are welcomed, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the order of integration in such a setting, I usually find it most convenient to describe the domains of integration by a chain of inequalities. In

$$\int_a^{y_0} \int_x^{y_0} g(t)\varphi'(x)\,dt\,dx$$

the variable $x$ of the outer integral varies from $a$ to $y_0$, and the variable $t$ of the inner integral varies from $x$ to $y_0$. So the domain of integration is

$$\{ (x,t) : a \leqslant x \leqslant t \leqslant y_0\}.$$

Now, if we change the order of integration, the inequalities say that $x$ varies from $a$ to $t$, and $t$ varies from $a$ to $y_0$. So

$$\int_a^{y_0} \int_x^{y_0} g(t)\varphi'(x)\,dt\,dx = \int_a^{y_0} g(t)\int_a^t \varphi'(x)\,dx\,dt.$$

For the second integral, it is analogous, the inequalities there are

$$y_0 \leqslant t \leqslant x \leqslant b.$$